# Force acronyms from glossary in a single line

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I wouldl ike to fix a problem I have with the following package:

> \usepackage[acronym,nomain,toc]{glossaries}

The issue is that I am not able to present one specific acronym in one single line, although there is enough space for it (see image below)

[image]

I had to set up the environment like this (seen from another post here) to avoiding grouping the acronyms:

```
\newglossarystyle{modsuper}{%
  \glossarystyle{super}%
  \renewcommand{\glsgroupskip}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2} & ##3\glspostdescription\space ##5\\[5pt]}%
}

\printglossary[style=modsuper, nonumberlist, title={List of Abbreviations}]
\clearemptydoublepage
```

However, even by changing the margins I couldn't make it.
Any tip about how to solve it? Thank you!

Comment: Hello and welcome to TEX.SX! Please, provide a minimal working example, that could be just copyed and tested upon. I am pretty sure that you need to just redefine command `\glsdescwidth`, which is set to `0.6\hsize`. Glossary style `super` is defined in file `glossary-super.sty`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your replay!
I could solved it by adding `\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{0.8\hsize}`
Sorry about the working example, my project has so many .tex sub-files and I didn't think about it in that moment