# Acronym glossary inconsistently prints entries

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I am having a problem with the consistency of how Overleaf prints glossary entries, specifically acronyms. I am trying to set it up in the appendix of the document.

When compiling it chooses to print some on-line with the acronym, while with others it inserts a virtual newline, and prints them below the actual acronym, I have attached a photo with an area marked below of how it looks.

[image]

I am trying to get it so that every entry is on a single line, including the definition and at what pages it is used. I have tried with the `\setglossarystyle` command, and while it will correctly compile when choosing altlist, or grouped, it refuses to cooperate when choosing list. I have tried to see if anyone else have had similar issues, and I found [this entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/561000/force-acronyms-from-glossary-in-a-single-line), and tried to get it to work, but with no luck.

The glossary command is used in the Preamble, the Main, and a Main file for the appendix, all whose code has been attached in this post, I have also included the glossary as it looks at the time of writing.

**Preamble:**

```
%%%Layout%%%
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,table,xcdraw]{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=3cm,vmargin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{doi}

%requirements setup
\setlist[description]{style=nextline}



%Macros for SI units
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\let\svqty\qty
\AtBeginDocument{\RenewCommandCopy\qty\SI} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\ifGm@preamble#1{\@firstofone}
\appto\restoregeometry{%
  \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
  \pdfpageheight=\paperheight}
  
\apptocmd\newgeometry{%
  \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
  \pdfpageheight=\paperheight}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{literate=
  {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
  {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
  {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
  {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
  {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
  {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
  {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
  {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
  {ã}{{\~a}}1 {ẽ}{{\~e}}1 {ĩ}{{\~i}}1 {õ}{{\~o}}1 {ũ}{{\~u}}1
  {Ã}{{\~A}}1 {Ẽ}{{\~E}}1 {Ĩ}{{\~I}}1 {Õ}{{\~O}}1 {Ũ}{{\~U}}1
  {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
  {ű}{{\H{u}}}1 {Ű}{{\H{U}}}1 {ő}{{\H{o}}}1 {Ő}{{\H{O}}}1
  {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
  {€}{{\euro}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1 {«}{{\guillemotleft}}1
  {»}{{\guillemotright}}1 {ñ}{{\~n}}1 {Ñ}{{\~N}}1 {¿}{{?`}}1 {¡}{{!`}}1 
}
\lstdefinestyle{MatLab}{ %Formatting for code in appendix
    language=Matlab,
    numbers=left,
    frame=L,
    stepnumber=1,
    showstringspaces=false,
    tabsize=1,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    commentstyle=\itshape\color{green!40!black},
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{blue},
}
\lstdefinestyle{C}{ %Formatting for code in appendix
    language=C,
    captionpos=b, 
    numbers=left,
    frame=L,
    stepnumber=1,
    showstringspaces=false,
    tabsize=1,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    commentstyle=\itshape\color{green!40!black},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    stringstyle=\color{orange!70!black},
}

\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{fancy}{
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the footer visible
}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\small\nouppercase\leftmark}
\rhead{\small\nouppercase\rightmark}
\rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Line at the header invisible
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the footer visible
}

\usepackage{calc}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{lastpage}

%%%Sprog og font%%%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{physics}
\let\qty\svqty
%%%Grafik%%%
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
%\definecolor{aaublue}{RGB}{33,26,82}% dark blue
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{%
  font=footnotesize,% set font size to footnotesize
  labelfont=bf % bold label (e.g., Figure 3.2) font
}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{lscape}
%%%Matematik%%%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[framed,amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\newenvironment{conditions}
  {\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} l}}
  {\end{tabular}\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}
\usepackage{textcomp}

%%%Overskrifter%%%
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\bfseries\huge}{\thechapter}{20pt}{\huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{10pt}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}

%%%Kommentarer%%%
\usepackage{verbatim} 

%%%Kildehenvisninger%%%
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sortcites,natbib=true,sorting=none,date=iso,seconds=true]{biblatex}
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{9000}
\addbibresource{Bib/Kilder.bib}

%%%Appendix og indholdsfortegnelse%%%
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
%\appto\appendix{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}

%Ændrer * til cdot notation
\mathcode`\*="8000
{\catcode`\*\active\gdef*{\cdot}}

%Pakke til SI enheder
\usepackage{siunitx}

%Pakke til glossary
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

%Pakke til .svg figurer
\usepackage{svg}

%Pakke til wrapfigure
\usepackage{wrapfig}

% Enable hyperlinks and insert info into the pdf file
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    pdfpagelabels=true,%
    plainpages=false,%
    pdfauthor={Author(s)},%
    pdftitle={Title},%
    pdfsubject={Subject},%
    bookmarksnumbered=true,%
    colorlinks=false,%
    citecolor=black,%
    filecolor=black,%
    linkcolor=black,% you should probably change this to black before printing
    urlcolor=black,%
    pdfstartview=FitH%
}

%\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{aaublue}{RGB}{33,26,82}% dark blue
\definecolor{mGreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mGray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mPurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backgroundColour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{CStyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backgroundColour},   
    commentstyle=\color{mGreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{mGray},
    stringstyle=\color{mPurple},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    breaklines=true,             
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2,
    language=C,
    tabsize=4,
    tabsize=2,
}
```

**Main**

```
 \input{Preamble/Preamble.tex}
\input{Preamble/AAUSynopsis.tex}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\add@text{}
\newcommand\tagaddtext[1]{%
  \gdef\add@text{#1\gdef\add@text{}}}% 
\renewcommand\tagform@[1]{%
  \maketag@@@{\llap{\add@text\quad}(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}%
}
\makeatother

\makeglossaries
\input{Bib/Glossary.tex}

\glsaddall[types=\acronymtype]

\newglossarystyle{custom_acronyms}
{
    \setglossarystyle{long3colheader}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%  
    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \textbf{\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}}
        & \glossentrydesc{##1}
        & ##2
        \tabularnewline}%
}

\begin{document}
\input{Formalia/Forside.tex}
\input{Formalia/Titelblad.tex}
\input{Formalia/Underskrifter.tex}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents

%Text
\input{Text/01 - Introduction/Introduction.tex}
\input{Text/02 - Problem Analysis/2.0 - Problem Analysis Main.tex}
\input{Text/03 - Requirements/Requirements Main.tex}
\input{Text/04 - Design/Design Main.tex}
\input{Text/05 - Implementation/ImplementationMain}
\input{Text/06 - Accept Test/TestMain}
\input{Text/07 - Discussion/DiscussionMain}
\input{Text/08 - Conclusion/ConclusionMain}
\BiblatexSplitbibDefernumbersWarningOff
%Sektions indelt kildeliste (indsæt keywords i kildelisten)
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,keyword={general},title={Bibliography}] 

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,keyword={image},title={Images}] 

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,keyword={datasheet},title={Datasheets}] 


\input{Text/09 - Appendix/Appendix.tex}


\end{document}
```

**The main of the appendix**

```
\part*{Appendix}
\setglossarystyle{list}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={Abbreviations}]
\include{Text/09 - Appendix/CAN_Bitfields}
\include{Text/09 - Appendix/Figures}
```

**Glossary**

```
%REMEMBER TO SORT ALPHABETICALLY
%\chapter{Glossary}\label{ch:glossary}

\newacronym{aau}{AAU}{Aalborg University}
\newacronym{fpga}{FPGA}{Field-Programmable Gate Array}
\newacronym{ram}{RAM}{Random Access Memory}
\newacronym{csi}{CSI}{Camera Serial Interface}
\newacronym{i2c}{I2C}{Inter-Integrated Circuit}
\newacronym{spi}{SPI}{Serial Peripheral Interface}
\newacronym{canbus}{CAN bus}{Controller Area Network bus}
\newacronym{leo}{LEO}{Low Earth Orbit}
\newacronym{fov}{FOV}{Field Of View}
\newacronym{ifov}{IFOV}{Instantaneous Field Of View}
\newacronym{csp}{CSP}{Cubesat Space Protocol}
\newacronym{cpu}{CPU}{Central Processing Unit}
\newacronym{esa}{ESA}{European Space Agency}
\newacronym{psk}{PSK}{Phase Shift Keying}
\newacronym{bpsk}{BPSK}{Binary Phase Skift Keying}
\newacronym{qpsk}{QPSK}{Quadrature Phase Shift Keying}

\newacronym{po}{PO}{Polar Orbit}
\newacronym{geo}{GEO}{Geostationary Orbit}

\newacronym{eps}{EPS}{Electronic Power Systems}
\newacronym{com}{COM}{Communication}
\newacronym{adcs}{ADCS}{Attitude Determination and Control System}
\newacronym{ais}{AIS}{Automatic Identification System}
\newacronym{fp}{FP}{Flightplanner}
\newacronym{ecu}{ECU}{Electronic Control Unit}
\newacronym{iso}{ISO}{International Standardization Organization}
\newacronym{usb}{USB}{Universal Serial Bus}
\newacronym{canh}{CANH}{CAN High}
\newacronym{canl}{CANL}{CAN Low}
\newacronym{can}{CAN}{Controller Area Network}
\newacronym{ieee}{IEEE}{The Institute of Electrical and Electronic Engineers}

\newacronym{p-pod}{P-POD}{Poly Picosatellite Orbital Deployer}
\newacronym{iod}{IOD}{In-Orbit Demonstration}

%Bitfields for can message frame
\newacronym{sof}{SOF}{Start Of Frame}
\newacronym{rtr}{RTR}{Remote Transmission Request}
\newacronym{ide}{IDE}{Identifier Extension}
\newacronym{dlc}{DLC}{Data Length Code}
\newacronym{crc}{CRC}{Cyclic Redundancy Check}
\newacronym{ack}{ACK}{Acknowledge}
\newacronym{eof}{EOF}{End Of Frame}
\newacronym{ifs}{IFS}{Interframe Space}
\newacronym{jpeg}{JPEG}{Joint Photographic Experts Group}

\newacronym{uhf}{UHF}{Ultra High Frequency}
\newacronym{vlc}{VLC}{Variable Length Encodig}

\newacronym{mipi}{MIPI}{Mobile Industry Processors Interface}

\newacronym{dct}{DCT}{Discreate Cosine Transform}

\newacronym{fec}{FEC}{Forward Error Correction}

\newacronym{bpp}{bpp}{bits per pixel}

\newacronym{bpc}{bpc}{bits per color}
\newacronym{mcu}{MCU}{Microcontroller Unit}
\newacronym{hdl}{HDL}{Microcontroller Unit}
```

I don't know if anyone here can see what might cause the issue, but any feedback is very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Added the entirity of where the glossary commands are used, as well as the glossary as it looks at the time of writing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please could you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces the salient parts of your screenshot.  Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we can see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Dai Bowen I have updated the initial post with the entireties of where the glossary commands are used. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the extra code we can cut it down to reproduce the issue with

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[description]{style=nextline}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{aau}{AAU}{Aalborg University}
\newacronym{fpga}{FPGA}{Field-Programmable Gate Array}
\newacronym{ram}{RAM}{Random Access Memory}
\newacronym{csi}{CSI}{Camera Serial Interface}
\newacronym{i2c}{I2C}{Inter-Integrated Circuit}
\newacronym{spi}{SPI}{Serial Peripheral Interface}
\newacronym{canbus}{CAN bus}{Controller Area Network bus}
\newacronym{leo}{LEO}{Low Earth Orbit}
\newacronym{fov}{FOV}{Field Of View}
\newacronym{ifov}{IFOV}{Instantaneous Field Of View}
\newacronym{csp}{CSP}{Cubesat Space Protocol}
\newacronym{cpu}{CPU}{Central Processing Unit}
\newacronym{esa}{ESA}{European Space Agency}

\glsaddall[types=\acronymtype]

\begin{document}
\setglossarystyle{list}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={Abbreviations}]
\end{document}
```

With the line

```
\setlist[description]{style=nextline}
```

being responsible.

Under the hood, the [`glossaries`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) list style is built on the `description` environment.
As you've redefined the style of `description` to be `nextline` with [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem), this puts the contents of the `\item` on a new line if the label is wider than the `leftmargin` of the list environment.
This is why only some acronyms (those with the widest short form) have their long form on a new line.

Assuming you want other `description` environments to be typeset with the `nextline` style, change the description environment just before `\printglossary` to restore it to normal.

```
\setlist[description]{style=standard}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={Abbreviations}]
```

The [`glossaries`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) `list` style and related styles should then behave as expected from the manual.

[image: Result of compiled code showing the acronym list from the glossaries package showing short and long form being defined on the same line]

Comment: Hi Dai, implementing the changes you made solved the issue. Thank you very much for your assistance.